# Error when running: make clean

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build some simulation software using makefile provided by them after I have made some changes to the libraries. But when I run make clean, it stops midway and I get the following error

---

```
rm: invalid option -- 'l'
Try `rm --help' for more information.
make: *** [neat] Error 1
```

---

I checked the man page for `rm` and there is no `-l` option, but I don't know why this command is being executed with `-l` option. Is there anyway to ignore this, or find out which specific file is causing the problem?

### EDIT:

- I have figured out the source of the error, but dont know how to edit it to make it work properly. Below is a snippet from an included Makefile with the faulty line:

  UDP_INTERFACE_SRCS = \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/interfaceudp_app.cpp \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/interfaceudp.cpp  \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/external_interface_udp.cpp \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/packet_send.cpp \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/addr.cpp \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/packet_capture.cpp -lpcap \
  $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/queue.cpp

In particular, the line: $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/packet_capture.cpp -lpcap \ 
is causing the error. What does the "-lpcap" added after "packet_capture.cpp" do? Now if I try to remove it, "make" gives an error saying:

```
./interfaces/extinterface/src/packet_capture.o: In function pcap_sniff_packets(void*)': /home/qualnet/4.5/main/../interfaces/extinterface/src/packet_capture.cpp:63: undefined reference to pcap_setdirection' make: *** [../bin/qualnet] Error 1
```

I checked the line number 63 in packet_capture.cpp in an effort to understand what -lpcap means. But I have no idea what that code does.

Comment: Can you show your make file ?

Comment: try make -n to see what it wants to do

Comment: @Andrej
Hey thanks make clean -n worked! what does that mean? what does -n option do?

Comment: @CodeBuzz
There are multiple Makefiles.. one Makefile which includes many more

Comment: @AndrejPanjkov
 make clean -n produces no errors.. BUT when i run "make" after "make clean -n", it says that there is nothing to be done for 'all'

Comment: @Nischal because -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
 Don't actually run any commands; just print them.

Comment: Trace what are you doing in clean target and where does rm gets that options

Comment: @pmod
Ok i had a look inside the Makefile.. The issue is with the line:

# Target "neat" removes all objects and (temporary) files with ~ at the
# end of the name.
#

neat:
        rm -f $(OBJS) core ../*/*~ ../*/*/*~

Now the macro OBJS is defined previously as:
#
# Define $(OBJS) for the cleanup rules.
# (macro not used for compilation)
#

OBJS = $(SIM_OBJS) $(RADIO_RANGE_OBJ) $(CONFIGPARSER_OBJ) $(MTS_OBJ) $(MTS2_OBJ)

Comment: i further removed different parts of the above macro and ran make clean.. and found out that the problem is with the $SIM_OBJS
Now $SIM_OBJS is defined as follows:
SIM_OBJS_PRE2 = $(SIM_SRCS:.C=.o)
SIM_OBJS_PRE1 = $(SIM_OBJS_PRE2:.c=.o)
SIM_OBJS = $(SIM_OBJS_PRE1:.cpp=.o)

I cannot make sense of what the above lines mean.. and how do i go about finding the specific file for which "rm" is throwing up an error

Comment: When you run `make clean`, can you see the command it executes? Try putting `echo SIM_JOBS: $(SIM_OBJS)` in the rule.

Comment: @Beta
When I put echo SIM_JOBS: $(SIM_OBJS) in the rule, i get the following when i run make clean:
rm -f ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range

Both the filenames dont start with -l, So why exactly am i getting the rm --'l' invalid option error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is clearly an iterative process, and the comments are getting long, so I'd better start an answer.)

You say: "When I put echo SIM_JOBS: $(SIM_OBJS) in the rule, i get the following when i run make clean: rm -f ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range"

This doesn't make sense. You should get something like

```
SIM_JOBS: ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range
rm -f ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range
```

or

```
SIM_JOBS: something/else
rm -f ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range
```

or at least

```
SIM_JOBS:
rm -f ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range
```

This suggests that you are looking at the wrong rule: the rule which produces `rm -f ../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range` is *not* the rule in which you put the `echo ...` command. If it *is* the rule and you were just being imprecise in the report, put this right above the `clean` rule:

```
SIM_JOBS=../bin/qualnet ../bin/radio_range
```

and tell us what happens.

**EDIT:**

1. Sorry, I wrote `SIM_JOBS` when I meant `SIM_OBJS`.

   The `echo` command was outside the rule, where it cannot work.

   It looks as if the problem. Could you edit your question to show the line you mentioned to @thiton, and a few previous lines? It looks as if the flag "-lpcap" is getting into a variable, where it doesn't belong.

**EDIT:**
The "-lpcap" is a kludge. My guess is that it's an option intended for the linker. Suppose you want to link a bunch of object files into an executable, and you want to search a certain library called "pcap":

```
gcc foo.o -lpcap bar.o baz.o
```

The order is very important; when the linker is searching for something, you want it to search foo.o first, then pcap, then bar, then baz. It's a question of precedence. But you want to store those filenames in a nice tidy variable, and how will you insert the `lpcap` at the right place? You could do it a good way, or use a lazy hack like this:

```
OBJECTS = foo.o -lpcap bar.o baz.o
gcc $(OBJECTS)
```

And if you're deducing the OBJECTS from the SOURCES, you have to put the hack in earlier:

```
SOURCES = foo.cc -lpcap bar.cc baz.cc
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
```

Whoever wrote these makefiles saved half an hour with this kludge, and it's taking you days to fix it. If you can confirm that this is what's happening, the easiest way is probably to split the list in two:

```
SOURCES_LEFT = foo.cc
SOURCES_RIGHT = bar.cc baz.cc
OBJECTS_LEFT = $(SOURCES_LEFT:.cc=.o)
OBJECTS_RIGHT = $(SOURCES_RIGHT:.cc=.o)
gcc $(OBJECTS_LEFT) -lcap $(OBJECTS_RIGHT)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Here is a snippet of the Makefile with echo included. Hope i have put it in the right place:

#
# Target "neat" removes all objects and (temporary) files with ~ at the
# end of the name.
#

neat:
        rm -f $(OBJS) core ../*/*~ ../*/*/*~

osneat:
        rm -f $(OS_OBJS) core ../*/*~ ../*/*/*~

#
# Target "clean" executes the rule for "neat", and deletes all
# executables.
#

echo SIM_JOBS:$(SIM_OBJS)
clean: neat
        rm -f $(SIM_EXEC) $(RADIO_RANGE_EXEC) $(CES_EXEC) $(MTS_EXEC) $(MTS2_EXEC)
        
realclean: clean kernelclean privateclean

Comment: When i run this, the echo statement is not being run.. the same rm with invalid option output is being displayed again. 

However I have figured out the culprit statement in one of the Makefiles that is included in the main Makefile. Could you kindly look at my comment in response to @thiton's answer and help me edit to work properly

Comment: Actually earlier i had put the echo statement inside the rule for the target "neat", coz the target clean has 'neat' as dependency. And when i ran "make neat", i was getting the same o/p as make clean.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Instead of the method of splitting it into two lines as you suggested, i tweaked the rm command in the "neat" rule.. as follows:

   `code` neat:
      rm -f -- $(OBJS) core ../*/*~ ../*/*/*~ `code`

The rule for "clean" has "neat" as dependency.. and the "--" tells that there are no further options.. Now make clean and make run without errors..

Answer (score 0):

Like @AndrejPanjkov noted in the comments, the standard tool to find out what exactly is going on in Makefiles is the `-n` (`--dry-run`) switch of make. It prints all commands as they would be run by the shell, even those normally silenced (e.g. via @).

Have a long, hard look in this output for any pattern like ' -l' (piping the output to less and using / helps). If that doesn't help, try running all commands output by -n by hand in make's shell (normally `/bin/sh`) or try removing all the silencers (`@` characters at a rule's start) from the Makefile and running make clean, checking the last line of output.

Comment: I have finally managed to find a line in a Makefile that is included in the main Makefile which is causing the problem.It reads as:

    $(UDP_INTERFACE_DIR)/packet_capture.cpp -lpcap  \
Can you tell me what the function "-lpcap" statement.

Comment: When i tried removing the "-lpcap" option. "make clean" runs without errors. But "make" throws up an error saying

 '../interfaces/extinterface/src/packet_capture.o: In function `pcap_sniff_packets(void*)':
/home/qualnet/4.5/main/../interfaces/extinterface/src/packet_capture.cpp:63: undefined reference to `pcap_setdirection'
make: *** [../bin/qualnet] Error 1'